# Implementation failure for Catmull-Clark algorithm

Tags: graphics3d

I am checking if there is any implementation available for the Catmull-Clark algorithm on subdivision surfaces, and found the following source:

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface

Unfortunately, when implementing the code for Wolfram Mathematica language, i only get the 1st step correctly. It seems that it has been recently edited, and there is something wrong when getting "newFaces". I don't entirely understand the way in which it is actually defined. Could anybody know how to fix it so that I can run it to generate those images?

Many thanks

Comment: You should complain to that website that the definition for `holeQ[]` is missing, and that the code posted there is unusable without it. In any case, please look at the linked thread, and if it does not suit your needs, edit your question to explain why.